# Unable to open a socket server

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to make a simple client and server connection. However the server does not seem to bind to the port appropriately.

The code I am using for the server is written below:

```
class Server extends Thread
{
    public boolean running = true;

    public Server(Main main) throws IOException
    {
        super();
        ServerSocket server_sock = new ServerSocket(8123);

        while (running)
        {
            new Connector(server_sock.accept(), main);
        }
        server_sock.close();
    }
}

class Connector extends Thread
{
    public Connector(Socket c)
    {
        super();
        system.out.println("Connecting"+c.getRemoteSocketAddress()+":"+c.getLocalPort());
        c.setKeepAlive(true);
        //wait for the connection to end
        system.out.println("Disconnecting"+c.getRemoteSocketAddress()+":"+c.getLocalPort());
    }
}
```

The client is rather simple, I just want to connect to the server (The lines shown below is run via another program in its main):

```
s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8123); // Start
s.close(); // Stop
```

What happens: the server runs and does not throw any exceptions. Hopeful I ran the client where it threw an exception `Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`.

So I made a simple python client & server pair to check the Java server / clients:

*Server:*

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 8123))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("CONNECTED: ", addr)
conn.close()
```

*Client:*

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 8123))
s.close()
```

I tested python server with python client as a sanity test, which worked just fine. I tested the python server with the java client and they both cooperated just fine. However, python client and java series does not work. My python server provides the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SIGABRT\Desktop\tcp.py", line 4, in <module>
    s.connect(('localhost', 8123))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Which typically means that the server is not started properly. So what am I doing wrong with the Java server client?

Comment: On a side note... Your user profile name on your computer is SIGABRT? Very nice.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Yes it is. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. For me, it helps to do

```
s = new Socket("localhost", 8123);
```

I wonder why it doesn't work with the IP...

#### Explanation

At least on my Ubuntu system, it seems like `new ServerSocket(port)` sets up a connection with IPv6 - "127.0.0.1" is IPv4 and cannot connect to the socket being set up. The alternative is to initialize the server socket with

```
new ServerSocket(port, 32, Inet4Address.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
```

I don't know if using IPv4 over IPv6 makes a real difference (performance-wise) when used via loopback address.